changing/fixing sorting tabs
the 'active' tab looks like it's just a 'most recent change'. maybe the word should just be 'recent' then? the word 'active' to me suggests something more like 'hot'. but then, how is the 'hot' tab sorted? ... and should it be sorted differently?

From this question on SO's Meta:

Active is based on creation / last
  modified time of any answer or the
  question itself. So the recently
  changed questions or new ones are in
  the active list.
Hot seems to be a mix of how recent
  the question and how busy it is.
  (votes, answers, comments etc)

See some of the linked questions from the above to get feel of how this all comes together.
By the way, there's also a newest tab that sorts by the time the question was asked.

that makes sense. really i was suggesting that the words should be changed because they don't represent the sorting going on. looks like i was right about 'active' - it's most recent change. which, again, is something totally different from something that's 'active' in my mind.

@allen Think of the naming like this:  the active tab shows things that have activity.  Things that have activity have recent changes.
